# SQL how to select the entries after a condition

Tags: sql, select, mariadb

After the following query:

```
SELECT
    my_table.ID,
    my_table.DATETIME,
    my_table.VALUE,
    diagnostics_keys.type as type,
    diagnostics_keys.key,
    diagnostics_keys.unit,
    diagnostics_policies.type as policy,
    pair_device_voucher.device_id,
    pair_device_voucher.voucher_id
FROM
    my_table
    inner join diagnostics_keys on my_table.DIAGNOSTIC_TYPE_ID = diagnostics_keys.ID
    inner join diagnostics_policies on my_table.POLICY = diagnostics_policies.ID
    inner join pair_device_voucher on my_table.DVP_ID = pair_device_voucher.ID
WHERE
    (
        (diagnostics_keys.type = 'AVGKMKWH')
        OR (diagnostics_keys.type = 'STATUS')
    )
    AND (
        DATETIME BETWEEN 1612515739000
        AND 1612516445000
    )
ORDER BY
    DATETIME ASC
```

I am getting the following results as they are in the image:

[image]

How can I adapt my query in order to select only the values that follow after the condition **type= status and value = 40** (the values inside of the red rectangles)? if the status is equal to 100 or something else, the entries under this do not filter.

Here are the two commands for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table( 
         ID varchar(255),
         Datetime_ varchar(255),
         Value_ varchar(255),
         Type_ varchar(255),
         Key_ varchar(255),
         Unit_ varchar(255),
         Policy_ varchar(255),
         Device_ varchar(255),
         Voucher_ varchar(255) )
```

```
INSERT INTO `my_table`(
                      `ID`, 
                      `Datetime_`, 
                      `Value_`, 
                      `Type_`, 
                      `Key_`, 
                      `Unit_`, 
                      `Policy_`, 
                      `Device_`, 
                      `Voucher_`)
             VALUES ('1','1612515739000','40','STATUS','203_sts','','periodic','12345','12345'),
('2','1612515745000','327.67','AVGKMKWH','0_202_avgkmKwh','Km/Kwh
','periodic','12345','12345'),
('4','1612515754000','40','STATUS','203_sts','','periodic','12345','12345'),
('3','1612515760000','327.67','AVGKMKWH','0_202_avgkmKwh','Km/Kwh
','periodic','12345','12345'),
('56','1612515775000','327.67','AVGKMKWH','0_202_avgkmKwh','Km/Kwh
','periodic','12345','12345'),
('6','1612515775000','327.67','AVGKMKWH','0_202_avgkmKwh','Km/Kwh
','periodic','12345','12345'),
('7','1612515790000','100','STATUS','203_sts','','periodic','12345','12345'),
('8','1612515805000','327.67','AVGKMKWH','0_202_avgkmKwh','Km/Kwh
','periodic','12345','12345'),
('9','1612515813000','327.67','AVGKMKWH','0_202_avgkmKwh','Km/Kwh
','periodic','12345','12345'),
('10','1612515820000','327.67','AVGKMKWH','0_202_avgkmKwh','Km/Kwh
','periodic','12345','12345'),
('11','1612515835000','40','STATUS','203_sts','','periodic','12345','12345'),
('12','1612515850000','327.67','AVGKMKWH','0_202_avgkmKwh','Km/Kwh
','periodic','12345','12345')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please define what defines "after"?  For instance, why are't all the rows selected after the first?  They are all after status = 40.

Comment: If status = 40 fetch the rows that follow. If the status is something else ignore the following values.

Comment: Are you saying `(diagnostics_keys.type = 'AVGKMKWH') OR (diagnostics_keys.type = 'STATUS' AND VALUE=40)` ?

Comment: The "database" tag is useless (it's implied with `sql` - you can't use SQL without a "database"). Please add a tag for the specific **product** you are using Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, ... [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: As I see you select rows between rows with value = 40 ans some other value with type = 'STATUS'. But it is only my guess, so you need to clarify the condition on which you need to start the frame and end the frame. Also please add some sample data because typing in such large and complicated dataset by hands is waste of time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I added queries for sample data.